# how to make html editor to be disable or read only

Tags: javascript, textarea, html-editor

I am getting html editor on my web page but I want it as un editable. how to do that?

```
<text area name="content" id="editor"></text area>
<script src="https://htmeditor.com/js/htmeditor.min.js" htmeditor_textarea="editor">
```

This is the code which I tried and I did got perfect html editor but I want it to be only editable on button before it should be disabled or read only(un editable).

Comment: does this really work in HTML? `<text area>...<text area>`

Comment: You probably need `textarea` tag, not `text` tag with `area` attribute.

Comment: From the "documentation", https://htmeditor.com/embed-html-editor/, it doesn't look like this offers many options to configure the behavior. This is based on the TinyMCE editor though, and that has an easy mechanism to toggle readonly-mode, https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-readonly-mode/ So I suppose you could try to make it readonly after the above script has done it's work - although it could be tricky to find the correct moment to do so, the TinyMCE will have to be properly initialized before.

Comment: It might perhaps make more sense, if you cloned https://htmeditor.com/js/htmeditor.js and used a modified local version, in which you set `readonly : 1` within the `tinymce.init` options; and then on click on your custom button, you _disable_ readonly as explained in the article I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change css classes into your html elements this solution can be your way to go:

You can add a wrapper div to your text area and script:

```
    <div id="parent-container" class="handle-no-events">
       <textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
       <script src="https://htmeditor.com/js/htmeditor.min.js" htmeditor_textarea="editor"></script>
    </div>
```

The example class "handle-no-event" when applied will prevent any edit on parent-container child elements, you can toggle or apply it again to enable/disable inputs on your editor.

Here what's inside handle-no-events class

```
   .handle-no-events {
       pointer-events: none;
   }
```

This method WILL NOT trigger the "disabled" state on input elements, so if you need to rely to this state in your editor elements the method provided is not viable